# using telerik ui for asp.net mvc vue.js

Tags: asp.net, user-interface, model-view-controller, vue.js, telerik

Has anyone used vue.js with Telerik UI for ASP.Net MVC? Not the Kendo UI controls?

Specifically looking for examples on using v-bind and v-model with the controls.

for example a checkbox

@Html.Kendo.Checkbox().Name()

I'd like to bind the name and set the checked and such like I've done for a standard html checkbox

```
type="checkbox" v-bind:id="thePlan.Id"    class="plan-selection" v-bind:checked="thePlan.IsSelected" v-model="thePlan.IsSelected"
```

Has anyone done something like this?

Answer (score 1):

You can add all HTML attributes you need using `new Dictionary<string, object>` in HtmlAttributes.

Like this:

```
@Html.Kendo().CheckBox().Name("checkBox").HtmlAttributes(new Dictionary<string, object> { { "class", "plan-selection" }, { "v-bind:id", "thePlan.Id" } })
```